# Access to Samba share via Thunar

Tags: xubuntu, samba, 22.04, thunar

after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 I can not connect to Samba share folder.
I tried it via Thunar(4.16.10) like ususal and it is not working.
smb://ip/share but on start of line I can see red exclamation mark in circle and command is not working

Do you have some idea pls?
Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after doing a minimal install with Xubuntu.

The solution for me was installing gvfs-backends and samba client, like so:
`sudo apt install gvfs-backends smbclient`

The clue was this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1645590/thunar-cannot-browse-network

Cheers.